# Unit Testing Database Methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am currently working on a c# project which makes use of an SQLite Database. For the project I am required to do unit testing but was told that unit testing shouldn't involve external files, like database files for the testing and instead the test should emulate the database.

If I have a function that tests if a something exists in a database how could this sort of method be tested with a unit testing.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQLite, you could use an [in-memory database](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). You can stage your database by inserting data and then run your tests against it.

Comment: I like the in-memory option but that's not really a unit test as @Boardy was told to do!?

Comment: Well, since the database runs in memory, there no real external dependency. If the test is strictly focused on the database query/result, I would consider it a unit test.

Comment: it depends on the situation, if the code is mainly just messing with sqlite, then its much more useful to test against it.   If sqlite is not central, then better off isolating and testing against an abstraction.

Comment: @John I thought the OP wanted to test database methods themselves... I might have missed the point though.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think that this is probably the best solution for what I want but all of the answers. Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 2):

in general it makes life easier if external files are *avoided* and everything is done in code.    There are no rules which says "shouldn't", and sometimes it just makes more sense to have the external dependency.  But only after you have considered how not to have it, and realized what the tradeoffs are.

Secondly, what Bryan said is a good option and the one I've used before.

Answer (score 2):

In an application that uses a database, there will be at least one component whose responsibility is to communicate with that database.  The unit test for that component could involve a mocked database, but it is perfectly valid (and often desirable) to test the component using a real database.  After all, the component is supposed to encapsulate and broker communication with that database -- the unit test should test that.  There are numerous strategies to perform such unit tests conveniently -- see the list of related SO questions in the sidebar for examples.

The general prescription to avoid accessing databases in unit tests applies to *non-database* components.  Since non-database components typically outnumber database-related components by a wide margin, the vast majority of unit tests should not involve a database.  Indeed, if such non-database components *required* a database to be tested effectively, there is likely a design problem present -- probably improper separation of concerns.

Thus, the principle that unit tests should avoid databases is generally true, but it is not an absolute rule.  It is just a (strong) guideline that aids in structuring complex systems.  Following the rule too rigidly makes it very difficult to adequately test "boundary" components that encapsulate external systems -- places in which bugs find it very easy to hide!  So, the question that one should really be asking oneself when a unit test demands a database is this: is the component under test legitimately accessing the database directly or should it instead collaborate with another that has that responsibility?

This same reasoning applies to the use of external files and other resources in unit tests as well.

Answer (score 1):

Once databases get involved it always blurs the line between unit testing and integration testing. Having said that, it is always a nice and very useful test to be able to put something in a database (Setup), Do your test and remove it at the end (Cleanup). This lets you test end to end one part of your application.

Personally I like to do this in an attribute driven fashion. By Specifying the Sql scripts to run for each test as an attribute like so ..

```
[PreSqlExecute("SetupTestUserDetails.sql")]
[PostSqlExecute("CleanupTestUserDetails.sql")]
public void UpdateUserNameTest()
    {
```

The connectionstrings come from the app.config as usual and can even be a symbolic link to the app.config in your main project.

Unfortunately this isn't a standard feature with the MS test runner that ships with visual studio. If you are using Postsharp as your AOP framework, this is easy to do. If not, you can still get the same functionality for standard MS Test Runner, by using a feature of .Net called "Context Bound Objects". This lets you inject custom code into an object creation chain to do AOP like stuff as long as your objects inherit from ContextBoundObject.

I did a blog post with more details and a small, complete code sample here.

http://www.chaitanyaonline.net/2011/09/25/improving-integration-tests-in-net-by-using-attributes-to-execute-sql-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

I think is really bad idea to have unit tests that depends on database information.
Also I think is a bad idea to use sqlite for unit tests.

You need to test objects protocol, so if you need something in your tests you should create them somewhere in the tests (usually at setUp).

Since is difficult to remove persistence, the popular way to do it is using SQLite, but always create what you need in unit tests.

**check this link [Unit Tests And Databases](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestsAndDatabases) this will be more helpful I think**

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use a mocking framework, to mimic a database.  For C# there is the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx).  Even the use of sqlite is an outside dependency to your code.