# Unit testing database code

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unit testing on code that uses the Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391249/unit-testing-on-code-that-uses-the-database)

I am just starting with unit testing and wondering how to unit test methods that are making actual changes to my database.  Would the best way be to put them into transactions and then rollback, or are there better approaches to this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472928/unit-test-insert-update-delete

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786750/unit-testing-database-methods/7803108#7803108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want proper test coverage, you need two types of tests:

- **Unit-tests** which mock all your actual data access. These tests will not acually write to the database, but test the behaviour of the class that does (which methods it calls on other dependencies, etc.)
- **System tests** (or **integration tests**) which check that your database can be accessed and modified. I would considered two types of tests here: simple plain CRUD tests (create / read / update / delete) for each one of your model objects, and more complex system tests for your actual methods, and everything you deem interesting or valuable to test. Good practices here are to have each test starting from an empty (or "ready for the test") database, do its stuff, then check state of the database. Transactions / rollbacks are one good way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing you need to mock or stub the data access code, mostly you have repository interface and you can stub it by creating a concrete repository which stores data in memory, or you could mock it using dynamic mocking framework ..

For system or integration testing, you need to re-create the entire database before each test method in order to maintain a stable state before each test.

Answer (score 1):

As per some of the previous answers if you want to test your data access code then you might want to think about mocks and a system/integration test strategy.

But, if you want to unit test your SQL objects (eg sprocs, views, constraints in tables etc) - then there are a number of database unit testing frameworks out there that might be of interest (including one that I have written).

Some implement tests within SQL, others within your code and use mbUnit/NUnit etc.

I have written a number of articles with examples on how I approach this - see http://dbtestunit.wordpress.com/

Other resources that might be of use:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/close-those-loopholes---testing-stored-procedures--/

http://tsqlt.org/articles/

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to have a way to mock you database actions.  So that your unit tests are not reliant on the database being available or in a certain state.  That said it also implies design that facilitates the isolation required to mock away your data layer.   Unit test and how to do it well is a huge topic.  Take a look on the googley for Mock Frameworks, and Dependency injection for a start.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test against a real database, this would be more of an integration then a unit test. Wrapping your tests in transaction could be an idea to keep your database in a consistent state.
We've done this in a base class and used the TestInitialize and TestCleanup functions to make sure this always happens.

But testing against a real database will certainly bring you into performance problems. So make sure from the beginning that you can swap your database access code with something that runs in memory. I don't now which database access code your targeting but design patterns like [UnitOfWork](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) and [Repository](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) can help you to isolate your database code and replace it with an in memory solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not developing an O/R mapper, there's no need to test database code. You don't want to test ADO.NET methods, right? Instead you want to verify that the ADO.NET methods are called with the right values.

Search Google for repository pattern. You will create an implementation of `IRepository` interface with CRUD methods and test/mock this.

Comment: I disagree. While ADO.NET may work fine, the way you're using it might not be fine. It's important to make sure your methods can actually write to the database and do the expected thing.

Comment: Yes, but when you are doing integration testing, for unit testing mocking a repository is sufficient

Comment: Yes - more than "sufficient", stubbing or mocking the repository is necessary for proper unit-testing. I was just saying that to have full functional coverage, you need both unit-tests and system-tests.

Comment: You're absolutely right.